# Android Button Losing onClickListener When Keyboard Opens

Tags: android, button, android-edittext, onclicklistener

I have a `EditText` field and a "Save" `Button` in my Android layout.

When the `Fragment` is created, I assign an `onClickListener` to the `Button`. The `Button` works correctly before the keyboard opens and after the keyboard closes, but seems to lose its `onClickListener` while I am editing the `EditText`.

Is there somewhere I need to reassign the `onClickListener` so it is available while the keyboard is open?

Here is the layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="top">

    <Button android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/add_comment_details"
            android:text="@string/done"
            android:id="@+id/done_button"
            android:textColor="@color/red_1"

        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_10"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/text_field2"
        android:layout_above="@id/done_button"
        android:hint="@string/enterText2"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:background="@drawable/add_comment_entertext"
        android:padding="20dp"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here's the code, in a `Fragment` where I'm adding the `onClickListener`

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.app_addcommentfragment, null);

        text = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.text_field2);
        done = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.done_button);

        done.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Log.i("MyFragment","onClick");
                doneListener.onClick(saveAndClose);
            }
        });
        return view;
    }
```

I am also using `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` in the `Manifest` so the `EditText` and the `Button` both stay on the screen when the keyboard opens.

Some more weirdness, if I switch the layout to this, the button works, but the button takes up most of the screen:

```
<EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/text_field2"
            android:hint="@string/enterText2"
            android:gravity="start"
            android:background="@drawable/add_comment_entertext"
            android:padding="20dp"
        />
<Button android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/add_comment_details"
                android:text="@string/done"
                android:id="@+id/done_button"
                android:textColor="@color/red_1"                 
                android:layout_below="@id/text_field2"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_10"/>
```

Comment: Please post the layout, as well.

Comment: Add 'onDestroyView()' to check if on keyboard opening, fragment calling this method

Comment: onDestroyView is not being called

Comment: What's the line: `doneListener.onClick(saveAndClose);`? I can't reproduce your issue, the click event is well logged in every situation..

Comment: `doneListener` just saves the data from the text field. Even if I comment that out, the `Log` message does not fire when the keyboard is open.